# probability of a single student not being accepted into any college

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are $n$ students applying to n colleges. Each college has a ranking over all students (i.e. a permutation) which, for all we know, is completely random and independent of other colleges. College number $i$ will admit the first $k_{i}$ students in its ranking. If a student is not admitted to any college, he or she might file a complaint against the board of colleges, and colleges want to avoid that as much as possible.

(a) If for all $i, k_i = 1$ (i.e. if every college only admits the top student on its list), what is the probability that all students will be admitted to at least one college?

(b) What is the probability that a particular student, Alice, does not get admitted to any college? Prove that if the average of all $k_i$'s is at least $2*\log(n)$, then this probability is at most $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. (Hint: use the inequality $1 —x \leq e^{-x})$

(Just to clarify, it says that the average of all $k_i$ is at least $2\ln n,$ NOT $21nn$.)

I'm having some problem trying to figure out part b.

First I tried picking an arbitrary college $i$, which accepts $k_i$ students. The college has $n!$ ways of ranking all the students. For Alice to note get admitted, we can select the $k_i$ students $(n-1) P k_i$ ways.

Then the probability simplifies down to $\frac{1}{(n-1-k_i)!}$

Now I want to extrapolate this, and the problem also gives that $\frac{k1 + \cdots + kn}{n} = 2 \ln n,$ but I'm not sure how to use that to give the result the problem wants. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Howdy, just a suggestion. Distil the questions so that they are more compact and mathjax them instead of making them image only,image only isn't searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{split}P(\text{not admitted})&=\left(\frac {n-k_1}n\right)\dots \left(\frac {n-k_n}n\right)&&\text{Alice is in bottom $n-k_i$ of each school's list}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{k_1}n\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{k_n}n\right)\\
&\le\prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\frac{k_i}n} && \text{the inequality in the hint}\\
&=e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{k_i}{n}}\\
&\le e^{-2\ln n} && \text{the condition in the problem}\\
&=\frac 1{n^2}\end{split}$$