# Finding the probability that at least 1 student doesn't get admitted to any college.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

[image]

[image]

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this problem. I'd posted a similar question before, where all $k_i$ were 1, but now that restriction is gone, and I'm having a harder time with this.

So $\text{P(at least 1 student does not get admitted to any college)} = 1 - \text{P(all students get admitted to at least 1 college)}$.

We are also given that $\frac{k_1 +... + k_n}{n} \ge 2 \ln(n)$.

Let the event A denote all students getting admitted to at least 1 college.

The problem is, I'm not sure how exactly to compute P(A), because while each college $i$ chooses $k_i$ students and accepts them, I need to make sure within the union of all of $k_i$ there is at least one of each student.

Without worrying about having everyone, I could just do :

> Each of the n colleges has n! possible list of students (hence $(n!)^n$ total possibilities).

> College 1 has n C $k_1$ students chosen, and has $(n - k_1)!$ permutations

> College 2 has n C $k_2$ students chosen and has $(n - k2)!$ permutations

> ...

> College n has n C $k_n$ students chosen and has $(n - k_n)!$ permutations.)

But since I have to have all students accepted into at least one college, I thought of doing for each College $i$, the college has $n - (i-1) C k_i$ students chosen and has $(n-k_i)!$ permutations. But then in this pattern, for College n, I'd be doing $1 C k_n$, which may be impossible.

How can I calculate P(A), or are there other "simpler" routes?

Comment: Probability that all students get admitted is $ \geq \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n$ and so probability that at least one student does not get admitted is $ \leq 1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n \leq \frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 3):

Previously you posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207225/probability-of-a-single-student-not-being-accepted-into-any-college), answered by "Jellyfish".

There it was shown that the probability that if $\dfrac{k_1+\cdots+k_n} n \ge 2\ln n$ then the probability that Alice is not admitted is $\le1/n^2.$ So you have

\begin{align}
& \Pr\Big( (\text{1st student not admitted) or (2nd student not admitted) or } \cdots \Big) \\[8pt]
\le {} & \Pr(\text{1st student not admitted}) + \Pr(\text{2nd student not admitted}) + \cdots \\[8pt]
\le {} & \frac 1 {n^2} + \frac 1 {n^2} + \cdots + \frac 1 {n^2} = n\cdot\frac 1 {n^2} = \frac 1 n.
\end{align}

If the non-admissions of different students were mutually exclusive events then the first $\text{“$\le$”}$ above would be $\text{“$=$”}.$

Comment: oh that's a great way to think about this, thank you! But I have a question—how do we have that the union is <= the sum? aren't they supposed to be equal?

Comment: oh nvm, I think the inequality is b/c of PIE right?

Comment: The are equal only if the events are mutually exclusive, and these events clearly are not mutually exclusive.